# Struts2 - name attribute refering to map

Tags: java, struts2

I have the following Struts2 code :

```
<s:iterator value="checkboxes">
    <tr>
        <th scope="row"><s:checkbox name="" fieldValue="true"/></th>
        <td><s:property value="key"/></td>
    </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

checkboxes is a hashmap associating a string with a boolean.
Now the question is what do I put in the name attribute of the checkbox.
Indeed, I'd like to write something like `name="checkboxes2.key"`
checkboxes2 is a hashmap similar to checkboxes but situated in the action class called when submitting the struts form.
key would be the key of checkboxes.

Comment: `name="checkboxes2['%{key}']"`.

Comment: Yeah that's what I found but it doesn't work. My checkboxes2 is still empty during the execution of the execute method.

Comment: If you want to display multiple checkbox's why are you not using a checkboxlist tag?

Comment: Show your action configuration and action class.